# nodejs mysql doesn't executes query and stops the script

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a database class with some methods to easily do some queries without formatting the values into a sql query string. So here is my delete method where the script is stopping.

```js
// Other Module

let filter = {
      url: 'http://www.example.com/some/route',
    },
    DB = new MySQL();

DB.delete(filter, 'found_urls').then(result => {
  console.log('The row/s are deleted.');
}).catch(error => {
  console.log('An error occured.');
  console.log(error);
});
```

```js
// MySQL.js

class MySQL {

    // some methods....

    delete(filter, table, operator = '=') {
      // Parse where clauses and create query string.
      let whereCondition = MySQL.parseColumnValue(filter, operator),
        sql = `DELETE FROM ${table}`;
      // whereCondition is an array: ["url = 'http://www.example.com/some/route'"]

      if (whereCondition.length > 1) {
        sql += ` WHERE ${whereCondition.join(' AND ')}`;
      }

      console.log(sql);
      // I get "DELETE FROM found_urls WHERE url = 'http://www.example.com/some/route'"

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('You can see me.');
        this.database.query(sql, (error, result) => {
          console.log('You never see me because the script stopped.');
          if (error) {
            reject(error);
            return;
          }

          resolve(result);
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

Some days ago it worked perfect but now it stops. I don't know what's wrong with this code.

**UPDATE**

This class would be used in a webcrawler so I think it's not necessary to protect it for SQL injection.

The table `found_urls` has about 200 rows, nothing is locked.

Bug I found my problem: A failure in another module. Without this module the crawler is running (with the delete operations).

Comment: `whereCondition.length < 1` condition is wrong. console `sql` and check what are you getting.

Comment: Unrelated: are you sure your approach correctly protects you from SQL injection? It seems to go against the use of parameterized queries.

Comment: More on the topic: are you sure it’s not just the query taking a long time? Have you checked what’s happening on the MySQL server (process list, logs)? How big is the table? What’s the actual query? Is there an appropriate index? Are there locks?